# Cox time-varying coefficient memory allocation issue

Tags: r, regression, survival, cox-model

I'm trying to add time-varying coefficients using the `tt()` function with `coxph` to solve the problem of PH violations in my Cox model.

When I try to do this I encounter the error:

> Cannot allocate vector of size...

I guess this is because of what `tt()` [does to the matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205475/time-varying-coefficients-in-cox-proportional-hazard-model) (and my dataset is n=100 000 with 135 variables), however, the problem is I'm using a remote server and I am limited to their capacities.

So, I guess my question is whether there may be other packages that are more memory efficient that would allow me to do this.

Each ID is represented by one record in the data and there are 1627 events.

Comment: How many unique time values are there? How many events among the 100,000 cases? Please edit the question to add that information, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Thanks for the tip, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not trying to use `tt()` to fit continuous functions of time for your coefficients in this case. With smaller data sets that helps describe and adjust for the pattern of associations of predictors with outcome over time. But even after you've done that I don't think that you can use `cox.zph()` to show that you "fixed" the proportional hazards (PH) problem. And with your large data set it seems to be impossible in practice, anyway, as you need to make up to 1627 copies (one per event time) of hundreds of thousands of data rows.

I'd recommend a few steps instead.

First, make sure that you are modeling continuous predictors flexibly, e.g. with regression splines, rather than as simple linear predictors. A poorly modeled continuous predictor can lead to apparent violation of PH, perhaps even for other predictors in the model.

Second, follow Frank Harrell's advice in a [comment on a related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584762/huge-confidence-intervals-in-a-covariate-in-regression#comment1080238_584762) and do some data reduction to cut down on the number of predictors. With 135 predictors you would expect about 7 of them to show "significant" violations of PH at p < 0.05; I understand that you only found [15 violators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/584743/28500) despite your large number of cases.

As you aren't interested in most of the predictors except for the [effects of levels of a `treatment`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/584743/28500), why use such a complicated model if you can adjust for the other predictors more simply? You are about at the limit of reliability for overfitting, with only about 12 events per predictor, so reducing the number of predictors could improve the precision of the parts of the model that you care most about. Section 4.7 of Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) or [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) describes data-reduction methods that can simplify the model without biasing results; all of Chapter 4 deserves close study.

Third, if you still have a PH problem after that, try stratification instead of the `tt()` function. Stratifying on levels of categorical predictors that fail PH should fix problems associated with them. You don't get regression coefficients for predictors on which you stratify, but if you're just adjusting for them you don't care about their coefficients.

To get hazard ratios you don't want to stratify your categorical `treatment` levels of primary interest, but you can still use *strata by time groups* that interact with your multi-level `treatment` predictor. That's described in Section 4.1 of the R survival [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf). With time strata you can use `cox.zph()` to evaluate PH.

If you use that approach to specify, say, 10 different time intervals you would only have to make 10 copies (at most, versus up to 1627 with `tt()`) of each of your 100,000 cases. That would probably fit into your computer, fix the PH problem if you choose appropriate time intervals, and would show how hazard ratios for `treatment` levels change with time, at whatever resolution you choose for the time intervals.

Comment: What a great answer Ed. I'm grateful as always. I maybe should have been clearer - although our main interest is the treatment, we still find it interesting to see coefficients of other covariates. This will limit the data reduction approaches available to us and to which variables we stratify. Oh and btw, with regard to modelling continuous predictors correctly, I of course used Martingale plots to check functional form; how can I check if the use of splines would improve my situation?

Comment: @JEDHK include splines in the model. Restricted cubic splines via `rcs()` in Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) provide a linear term and additional nonlinear terms modifying it. The `survival` package provides penalized smoothing splines via its `pspline()` function. Both allow for tests on nonlinearity. It's best to decide ahead of time how many degrees of freedom/knots to allocate to each continuous predictor and then stick with that for inference. See Chapters 2 and 4 of Harrell's [notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) or [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ed! I used 'pspline()' to add cubic splines of the continuous variables that violated the PH assumption and now the assumption is satisfied. That's great (in theory), but I checked the Schoenfeld plot for one of the covs (as I believe I've seen Harrell suggest doing) and the shape of the curve looks basically the same, though now the Y-axis is zoomed out (i.e., what was 0.1 is now around 1). This surprises me - I expected a straight horizontal line after fitting the spline. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @JEDHK those plots are hard to interpret for spline terms, as they combine all of the multiple associated coefficients into 1 plot. I also see that behavior with `pspline()` or `rcs()` splines if you accept the default `terms=TRUE` in the call to `cox.zph()`. With an `rcs()` spline you can examine each spline coefficient individually if you specify `terms=FALSE`, but the penalization with `pspline()` doesn't seem to allow for that. Do check how many degrees of freedom you used up with your `pspline()`terms; if you had a lot of them you might be in danger of overfitting.

Comment: I went for 5 as I believe Harrell suggests (RMS, page 28) that for large datasets (>100) we can afford up to 5 knots. Since I have 100k I thought 5 seemed reasonable. I was also wondering about the individual associated coefficients - what's my interpretation for them then? That is, how can I calculate the contribution to the final model of the continuous variable that I've applied pspline to?

Comment: @JEDHK 5 df per continuous predictor is OK, but think about the total over all such predictors. With 1627 events you shouldn't be using up more than 80-160 df _total_ for _all_ predictors after taking penalization into account. You can't directly interpret individual `pspline` coefficients. For predictor contributions to the model, use combined type II Wald test chi-square values, e.g. from `car::Anova`. Harrell recommends subtracting the df from each to "level the playing field" among predictors of varying complexity. I find this easier with `rcs` splines and the `rms` package.

Comment: Total df is 130, so I understand I'm still in range (albeit a little on the high side - I'm looking into data reduction still). TBH, pspline seems to solve the PH issue whereas they were still significant with rcs. So I'm inclined to stick with pspline, since the PH issue was the original reason for adding splines anyway